# Query to show multiple table values in one custom admin grid without any relationship in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2

Query to show multiple table values in one custom admin grid without any relationship in magento2.2.5?

I think it can be done using **Raw query**.

But I am not sure how to implement it.

Any help would be appreciated